# Unable to delete specific document from cosmos db via sdk?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

[image]I am using DeleteDocumentAsync as per below code.

```
 public static void DeleteErrorLog(List<string> LogID, string collectionName)
        {
            FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };
            try
            {
                //getting resource id for a document with given logid

                var db = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(x => x.Id == databaseName).ToList().First();
                var coll = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(db.SelfLink).Where(x => x.Id == collectionName).ToList().First();
                var docs = client.CreateDocumentQuery(coll.SelfLink, queryOptions).Where(x => x.Id == LogID[0]).AsEnumerable().Single();
                var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, docs.ResourceId);
                client.DeleteDocumentAsync(collectionUri);

            }
            catch (Exception) { throw; }
        }
```

Every value is populating correctly and I am getting the document that I need to delete still unable to delete it? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You're not awaiting `client.DeleteDocumentAsync`, which means your `catch` will not catch exceptions that occur in this task.  My guess is that there is an exception being thrown but not caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing the PartitionKey for the delete operation:

```
var documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, LogID[0]);
client.DeleteDocumentAsync(documentUri, new RequestOptions(){PartitionKey=new PartitionKey(LogID[0])}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Also, if you already know the Id, which in your case is `LogID[0]`, you don't need the Query.

Comment: I tried this and put “id” since thats my partition key however still documents are not deleting.

Comment: You don't have to put the name of the attribute, but the value. I edited my response based on your comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot this works.I was trying to delete the document by passing resource id however the partition key was id.Once I passed id and specify the partition key everything worked as expected.Thanks

Comment: Just remember to add `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` at the end if you want to execute this synchronously. Otherwise you are firing a thread and losing it. Ideally you would do all this async.

Answer (score 1):

You're not awaiting `client.DeleteDocumentAsync`, which means your `catch` will not catch exceptions that occur in the `Task` that's created - it will silently fail.

My *guess* is that due to this, there is an exception being thrown in `DeleteDocumentAsync` that's not subsequently caught where expected.

Ideally, this method would be re-written to use `async`/`await`, then your `try` `catch` will pick up any exceptions being thrown:

```
public static async Task DeleteErrorLog(List<string> LogID, string collectionName)
{
    ...
    await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(collectionUri);
    ...
}
```

You'll have to make sure that the code calling this method also uses `await`.

Comment: The reason for this code to be a synchronous code is its a part of a large code base and contains a multiple methods in hierarchy. In order to make it asnc I have to define task and await in multiple chain so kept it this way